# Stretch SVG to fit 100% height and width of its parent

Tags: html, css, svg

(Solved - see solution via codepen link)
I am trying to use an SVG image as a background that will always stretch to 100% of its parent div.
Already tried:

- Use as CSS background-image and set background-size: 100% 100%.
- Put absolute to parent div and set height:100%.
- preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax".
- even if I manually change the viewBox it dosen't work.
- tried all the related questions I found here - [Stretch SVG background image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39418463/stretch-svg-background-image), [Automatically scale an SVG to its parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19191154/automatically-scale-an-svg-to-its-parent), [Fit/Stretch SVG to div background without reescaling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220417/fit-stretch-svg-to-div-background-without-reescaling)

To get better understanding of what I want, please visit this link:
http://185.127.16.178/~amen/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%97%D7%A0%D7%AA-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94/

In that green bubble, the text's length can vary, so I need the SVG to stretch when more text is added and the div is growing.

I also created a small pen -

```css
.svg-container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

#small_bubble {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cls-1 {
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: green;
  stroke-miterlimit: 3;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

.e-poa {
  position: absolute;
}

e-por {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <svg id="small_bubble" class="e-poa" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 311.92 272.85" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax">
      <path class="cls-1" preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax" d="M301.52,1.57,8.37,19.53A7.87,7.87,0,0,0,1.5,27.34V214.76a7.89,7.89,0,0,0,7.12,7.85l46.67,4.53-7.14,42.78,63-37.35,190.58,18.51a7.88,7.88,0,0,0,8.65-7.85V9.38A7.88,7.88,0,0,0,301.52,1.57Z"/>
     </svg>
</div>
```

Solution can be seen here (Solved by - @Furkan Poyraz):
https://codepen.io/ncamaa/pen/JZzeQM

[image]

Comment: I would split the shape in two ... the top part and the bottom part and you link both with border

Comment: I thought about it, but the width of the div may also vary, so the border width won't perfectly scale with the SVG border width.

Comment: Changing preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMax" to preserveAspectRatio="none" should do the trick, but I'd recommend you to just create a shape with css.

Comment: @Nadav as I see in code pen you find a solution you can post it as answer to help more people in future...

Answer (score 5):

If you are open to another alternative you can create the shape with pure CSS. It won't be neat as the SVG one but it will be responsive:

```css
* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}

.box {
 margin:40px;
 padding:0 10px;
 max-width:200px;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;
 border-right:2px solid green;
 border-left:2px solid green;
 position:relative;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  bottom:calc(100% - 40px);
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid green;
  border-bottom:0;
  border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
  transform:skewY(-5deg);
  transform-origin:left bottom;
}
.box .b {
  position:absolute;
  left:-2px;
  right:-2px;
  top:calc(100% - 40px);
  height:50px;
  border:2px solid green;
  border-top:0;
  border-radius:0 0 5px 5px;
  transform:skewY(5deg);
  transform-origin:left top;
}
.box .b:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  top:calc(100% - 15px);
  left:40px;
  border-left:2px solid green;
  border-bottom:2px solid green;
  transform:skewY(-45deg);
}
.box .b:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  width:27px;
  height:4px;
  top:calc(100% - 1px);
  background:#fff;
  left:42px;
}
.box p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis est lorem, ultricies vel iaculis id, accumsan quis risus. In posuere arcu id metus tincidunt, in eleifend nisl dapibus. Ut viverra felis nec pretium accumsan. Sed eu ante id augue placerat pellentesque eget at nibh. Quisque pharetra nisi et suscipit eleifend</p>
<span class="b"></span>
</div>
<div class="box">
<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis est lorem, ultricies vel iaculis id, accumsan quis risus. In posuere arcu id metus tincidunt, in eleifend nisl dapibus.</p>
<span class="b"></span>
</div>
<div class="box" style="max-width:300px;">
<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis est lorem, ultricies vel iaculis id, accumsan quis risus. In posuere arcu id metus tincidunt, in eleifend nisl dapibus.</p>
<span class="b"></span>
</div>
<div class="box" style="max-width:350px;">
<p>orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis est lorem, ultricies vel iaculis id, accumsan quis risus.</p>
<span class="b"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Impressive CSS skills. Right now this is the best solution. Will wait to see if someone can solve it using SVG. I'll be surprised if there is no SVG vertical stretch option.

Comment: @Nadav yes of course, you should wait for some SVG wizards, am sure there is a solution ;)